# How to split a string in python with a remainder?

Tags: python, split

In python3 I have e.g. the following string

```
 433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher
```

which I want to split in four parts: the first three elements (the numbers) and the remainder as one string. Of course its possible to do it the following way:

```
text = " 433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher"
pid,rss,etime,*remainder = text.split()
cmd = ' '.join(remainder)
```

but maybe there is a more pythonic way to do that?

Comment: you could consider using https://psutil.readthedocs.io/ . that does not help with string splitting but with process info in python...

Comment: I don't think that is a good duplicate for this question, that is not what the OP is asking

Comment: Its pythonic already.

Comment: @CoryKramer Isn't it? As I see it, it's exactly the same question with `maxsplit=1`.

Comment: Now that I think about it yeah you're right that's a good solution, but with `maxsplit=3`, then that would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with the `maxsplit` parameter:

```
text = " 433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher"
text.strip().split(maxsplit=3)  # max 3 splits
# ['433', '65040', '9322', '/opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher']
```

Comment: note to future self: 3 splits gives 4 outputs